# Two pipes cement truck time equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two pipes are used to pump a cement mixture out of a truck.

The pipes work at the same rate.

When pipe A works alone it can empty the truck in 45 minutes.

When both pipes are used together they empty the truck in $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time that it takes pipe B to empty the truck when it works alone.

Suppose pipe B takes $x$ hours to empty the truck when it works alone.

Which one of the following equations can be used to find $x$?

1) $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2}{3x}$

2) $x+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{3}{2x}$

3) $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2x}{3}$

4) $x+\frac{3}{4}=\frac{2x}{3}$

5) $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{3}{2x}$

visual representation note:

[image]

**My attempt**

1)$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2}{3x}$

$x=-\frac{1}{4}$

2) $x+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{3}{2x}$

$x=-\frac{4-\sqrt{70}}{6}, -\frac{4+\sqrt{70}}{6}$

3) $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2x}{3}$

$x=1-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2},1+\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$

4) $x+\frac{3}{4}=\frac{2x}{3}$

$x=-\frac{9}{4}$

**Answer:**

5) $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{3}=\frac{3}{2x}$

$x=\frac{3}{8}$

Comment: Are you posting homework on this site? This question is likely to be closed unless you tell us what your efforts are in solving this question i.e. where you are getting stuck, and what is your confusion at that point.

Comment: Not homework, old exams. Learning how to use MathJax and LaTeX. Working through it and will post the answer when I understand it.

Comment: I'm lost here... how would I go about answering this? 

All I could go on was to simplify the 5 equations. I'm basically going with the answer that seems the most likely. What would you do to get to the answer?

Comment: @RyanRulingRama I´ve posted an answer. If you have any question about it, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If pipe A needs $\frac{3}{4}h$ (=45 min) to fill the truck then it can fill $\frac{4}{3}$ trucks in one hour.

And pipe B can fill  $\frac{1}{x}$ of a truck in one hour. Let $t$ the hours within both pipes can fill one truck. Then the following equation can be constructed:

$\left(\frac{4}{3}+ \frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot t=1 \ (\texttt{truck})\quad (1)$

Now we know following:

> When both pipes are used together they empty the truck in $\frac23$ of the
>   time that it takes pipe B to empty the truck when it works alone.

That means, that $t=\frac23 x$. You can insert the expression for $t$ in $(1)$.

$\left(\frac{4}{3}+ \frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot \frac23 x=1 \quad $

*multiplying out the brackets*

$\frac{8}{9} x+\frac23 =1 $

Finally you multiply the equation by $\frac{3}{2x}$ and you will get the equation, which is one of solutions.